# IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 8.22.2 - No Register View anymore

Tags: arm, iar, cortex-m

Am I the only one who is missing the register-view in IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM Version 8.22.2 (the latest)?
As described here https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/debugging-with-microcontroller-registers/ there should be a button "View -> Register" to show all registers (like GPIO etc.). But I miss that button!
The only way how I can take a look at register contents while debugging is by typing in their memory adresses - which is beyond inconvenient

Using ST-Link V2 via SWD and a STM32F103.

Answer (score 0):

You can now go to "View -> Registers -> Registers 1" and then "RMB -> View Group". A bit inconvenient but it works.

Comment: Note: RMB Stands for "Right mouse button". And yes, it works.